# Test method that takes function literal in scala

Tags: scala, specs2

I am using specs2 to test the following class

```
class ConstraintSolver {
  def solve(solver: Solver)(callback: (ConstraintSolution) => Unit) = {
    val results = solver.solve()
    callback(ConstraintSolution(true, results))
  }
}

case class ConstraintSolution(isSuccessful: Boolean, results: Map[String, Variable])
```

I want my test to assert on the 'results' variable passed into the callback function. So far, this is what I have:

```
class ConstraintSolverSpec extends Specification {
  "ConstraintSolver" should {
    "solve a matching problem and report the solution" in {
      val constraintSolver = new ConstraintSolver()

      val solverWithCapacityConstraints = ....
      constraintSolver.solve(solverWithCapacityConstraints) {
        constraintSolution => {
          constraintSolution.isSuccessful shouldEqual true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this does not work. I've checked online and can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "does not work"?

Comment: How about mocking your callback?

Comment: @Łukasz I get error "could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.main.CommandLineAsResult[Unit]". think it required an assertion in the main body of the test so I added "success" at the bottom and that fixed it.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg, thanks. Yes that should work too. Will just test it and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock your callback with Mockito:

```
class ConstraintSolverSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
  "ConstraintSolver" should {
    "solve a matching problem and report the solution" in {
      val constraintSolver = new ConstraintSolver()
      val callbackMock = mock[(ConstraintSolution) => Unit]

      val solverWithCapacityConstraints = ....
      constraintSolver.solve(solverWithCapacityConstraints)(callbackMock)

      // now check
      there was one(callbackMock).apply(
        beLike[ConstraintSolution] { case solution =>
          solution.isSuccessful should beTrue
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```